# Filter json based on schema c# Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to remove fields in the json string that are not defined in the schema.
I know this is what a normal deserialization does, it will discard extra properties to fit into the concrete class. But I also want to keep the original json string, for the parts that is not filtered out.
Example:

```
class ConcreteClass
{
string ProA;
string ProB;
}

jsonstring = @"{
'ProA' : 'value1',
'ProC' : 'value2'
}";
```

What I need is: 'ProC' is filtered out, since it's not in the schema, keep 'ProA' only, and 'ProB' is not in the filtered string since it wasn't before the filtering.

the result should be:

```
filteredString = @"{ 'ProA' : 'value1' }";
```

The reason I'm doing this is, I need to differentiate 'property doesn't exist' vs 'property value is null'. So I want to filter out fields not defined by schema first and then keep whatever is left.

Comment: Your original question was tagged [tag:jsonschema] until somebody removed it.  Are you actually filtering against a [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) using [Json.NET Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) or you filtering against a *`Type`* such as `ConcreteClass`?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? I want to filter out additional properties without using a concrete type.